# "A error occurred during the signature verification." during apt-get update

Tags: 10.04, server, apt, updates

I just did a fresh installation of Ubuntu 10.04LTS server without any issues.

However, the apt-get update or aptitude update is giving the following errors:

```
a. bzip2:(stdin) is not bzip2 file.ign for all lines
```

Plus the following errors :

```
Fetched 3,582B in 0s (74.1kB/s)
Reading package lists...
W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.GPG error: //security.ubuntu.com lucid-security Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.GPG error: //in.archive.ubuntu.com lucid Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.GPG error: in.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
W: Failed to fetch security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-security/Release  
W: Failed to fetch in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Release  
W: Failed to fetch in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-updates/Release  
W: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Please guide in resolving this error .

Comment: Please open the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` select everything, copy it to the clipboard, *edit your question*, and paste it in. From the error message, it looks to me like some of the URLs in that configuration file may be corrupt. Providing the contents of that file will show if that is the case and, if so, how to fix it. Please also open a Terminal window, run the command `ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d`. That will give some information about PPAs and other software sources besides the primary ones (if there are any).